# Python os.getlogin() vs BASH : who

Tags: command-line, bash, python, python3

I have formed 3 sessions with user accounts and I got no problem with Unix: who command but why I am unable to get correct response with python : getoslogin() function.

Please find attached image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the official documentation of `os` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getlogin):

```
os.getlogin():

Return the name of the user logged in on the controlling terminal of the process
```

As the user `raja` is logged in on the tty where the `python` process is running, you are correctly getting the output `raja`.

To get what you want you can use the `subprocess` module to run native Linux commands on `python`:

```
$ who
foobar   :0           2015-11-01 18:04 (:0)
foobar   pts/1        2015-11-01 18:04 (:0)
foobar   pts/9        2015-11-01 18:04 (:0)


>>> python2
>>> import subprocess
>>> print subprocess.check_output("who")
foobar   :0           2015-11-01 18:04 (:0)
foobar   pts/1        2015-11-01 18:04 (:0)
foobar   pts/9        2015-11-01 18:04 (:0)
```

Or check the [`get_users()`](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation) function from [`psutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) package.

Comment: Thank you , But as I have googled I think there is no way of getting it, is it ? I have to more research.

Comment: @Raja Check my edits please..